# SendBird Error 400403 Invalid value: JSON body

Tags: python, sendbird

I am trying to create user using send bird API
I am using python to make the API call, but getting error code 400403,
If I try from postman it works, not sure where I'm going wrong in the code

**Following is my code -**

```
import json
import requests

url = ‘https://api-someappidhere.sendbird.com/v3/users’

headers = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf8',
    'Api-Token' : 'secondaryApiToken'
}

data = {
    'user_id' : 'someuserId',
    'nickname' : 'somenickname',
    'profile_url' : ''
}

try:
    apiResponse = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    apiResponse = apiResponse.json()
    
    return response

except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

**I am getting the following response -**

```
{
    "hasError": false,
    "result": {
        "message": "Invalid value: \"JSON body.\".",
        "code": 400403,
        "error": true
    }
}
```

**References -**
https://docs.sendbird.com/platform/quick_start
https://docs.sendbird.com/platform/error_codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `json.dumps()`.

```
import json
import requests

url = ‘https://api-someappidhere.sendbird.com/v3/users’

headers = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf8',
    'Api-Token' : 'secondaryApiToken'
}

data = {
    'user_id' : 'someuserId',
    'nickname' : 'somenickname',
    'profile_url' : ''
}

jsonData = json.dumps(data)

try:
    apiResponse = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=jsonData)
    apiResponse = apiResponse.json()
    
    return response

except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

Comment: @Ani I think this is JSON API so to use it you should post JSON data. and JSON is a string. so short answer is yes.